# Parameterized Queries not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, parameterized-query

I had the following implementation of filling a `DataTable` with `SQL`:

```
var con = new SqlConnection();
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
var dt = new DataTable();
string sSQL = @"SELECT LogID, Severity, Title
                FROM dbo.Log
                WHERE UPPER(LogID) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                        OR UPPER(Severity) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                      OR UPPER(Title) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                    ORDER BY " + orderBy + " " + orderFrom + @"
                OFFSET ((" + (Convert.ToInt32(current) - 1).ToString() + ") * " + rowCount + @") ROWS
                FETCH NEXT " + rowCount + " ROWS ONLY;";

try
{
    using (var connection = THF.Models.SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```

This works nicely but I've realized that this is dangerous due to SQL Injection. So I've tried to solve that danger using parameterized queries like this:

```
var con = new SqlConnection();
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
var dt = new DataTable();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("@searchPhrase", searchPhrase.ToUpper()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("@orderBy", orderBy));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("@orderFrom", orderFrom));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("@current", current));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("@rowCount", rowCount));

string sSQL = @"SELECT LogID, Severity, Title
                FROM dbo.Log
                WHERE UPPER(LogID) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                        OR UPPER(Severity) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                      OR UPPER(Title) LIKE '%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + @"%'                    ORDER BY " + orderBy + " " + orderFrom + @"
                OFFSET ((" + (Convert.ToInt32(current) - 1).ToString() + ") * " + rowCount + @") ROWS
                FETCH NEXT " + rowCount + " ROWS ONLY;";

try
{
    using (var connection = THF.Models.SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```

Unfortunately now my data table doesn't fill. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using the parameters in the query.  I would expect to see `@searchPhrase`, etc. in the query string itself.  However, one problem is that you cannot parameterize column names, so the `ORDER BY` presents a challenge.

Comment: You are not using `cmd` at all in your second example.

Comment: You are using 2 different SqlCommand objects. One that you add parameters to and you then create a new one with your SQL string. Also note that your SQL string isn't using your parameters.

Comment: What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are using multiple command and connection references, not sure if thats a copy/paste problem or your actual code is like that. In the second case it will not even compile.
- Reference the parameters directly in your query, see below. Sql Server uses named parameters so the same parameter can be reused in multiple locations.
- Desc/Asc cannot be used as a parameter. You should double check the value though or use an enum and pass that (recommended).
- The same is true of the numeric values for rowcount, pass those in as numbers or check their values using a TryParse to ensure it is numeric and not malicious code.
- The default install options for Sql Server is for a case insensitive coalition. This means you do not have to `UPPER` a string to do a comparison. If you do have a case sensitive install then do not change this, otherwise remove all calls to `UPPER` when doing comparisons.
- Finally you well never know why your code is not working if you surround your code in `try/catch` and have an empty `catch` block. Your code will fail silently and you will be left scratching your head. Do not do this anywhere in your code, it is bad practice!! Either catch the exception and handle it (do something so code can recover) OR log it and rethrow using `throw;` OR do not catch it at all. I chose the later and removed it.

---

Code

```
var currentNum = Convert.ToInt32(current) - 1;
var temp = 0;
if(!"desc".Equals(orderFrom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !"asc".Equals(orderFrom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    throw new ArgumentException("orderFrom is not a valid value");
if(!int.TryParse(rowCount, out temp))
    throw new ArgumentException("Rowcount is not a valid number");

var dt = new DataTable();
string sSQL = @"SELECT LogID, Severity, Title
                FROM dbo.Log
                WHERE UPPER(LogID) LIKE @searchPhrase
                OR UPPER(Severity) LIKE @searchPhrase                      
                OR UPPER(Title) LIKE @searchPhrase                    
                ORDER BY @orderBy " + orderFrom + "
                OFFSET ((" + currentNum.ToString() + ") * " + rowCount + @") ROWS
                FETCH NEXT " + rowCount + " ROWS ONLY;";

using (var connection = THF.Models.SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection())
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchPhrase", "%" + searchPhrase.ToUpper() + "%"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@orderBy", orderBy));

    connection.Open();
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: ORDER BY @orderBy will order by const , guess it isn't what OP needs.

Comment: Did a little biut of tweaking with the `@orderBy` and that fixed it. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how this should be done.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into tbl_insert values(@name,@email,@add)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtadd.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```